# Over salted kimchi

Tags: salt, fermentation, kimchi

I made sprouted soybean kimchi but it turns out I used too much salt. Is there a way to compensate for that now or is it too late to save the taste ?

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: Don't worry too much about it - and the voter's not likely to see the comment. If I had to take a wild guess, it might've been someone who thinks the answer's obvious so it's not a very useful question, or it might've been an accident. But... not everything's obvious to everyone, so the question's fine, and you indeed got upvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been there, so I can tell you from experience that it is too late. The only thing you could do is mix it with a new batch of undersalted kimchi, but that is far more trouble than it is worth.

Another option, which is highly dependent on how oversalted your kimchi is, would be to cook with it. If you do not salt the dish, you could use it in fried rice or something similar with some degree of success (again, speaking from experience).